# How to make files downloaded using DownloadManager accessible only from my app?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I download some files in my app using the following `DownloadManager.Request`:

```
Request request = new Request(Uri.parse(url));          
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),    
    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename);
```

For legal issues, I want the files to be only accessible from the app.

Using my code I can see the files in the Download Manager app and I can share them from there.

How can I make the files only accessible and visible from my app?

Comment: You can't if the user is root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I make the files only accessible and visible from my app?

Stop using `DownloadManager` and download the file yourself directly to internal storage.

Or, as soon as the file is downloaded, move it to internal storage. This will leave a window when the file is on external storage, though.